# Что делает команда journalctl -since «tomorrow»?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, centos

Как правильно понимать эта команду systemd?
journalctl —since "tomorrow"
Правильно ли я понимаю её как команду показать сообщения начиная с завтра.

Answer (score 1):

Да, всё верно.

> --since= <..>
>
> If the date component is omitted, the current day is assumed.
>   Alternatively the strings "yesterday", "today", "tomorrow" are
>   understood, which refer to 00:00:00 of the day before the current day,
>   the current day, or the day after the current day, respectively.

Источник: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html

Comment: Но я разве могу посмотреть сообщения за затрышние сутки?

Comment: можете. только там будет пусто.

Comment: А могу я задам на перёд запрашивать фильтр? Например, с завтра до вчера.

Comment: Да, --since="tomorrow" --until="yesterday"